# Can't update a single doc in Mongo with Node

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, put

Hopefully someone can point out my error here.

In my app a user clicks on a button to insert a doc into the database. When they click on another button, a timestamp is added to an array.

Here's the code to create the doc (it works):

```
// Add User
function addUser(event) {
event.preventDefault();

ident = makeWords(2);

    var newUser = {
        'ident' : ident,
        'group': '',
        'timestamps': [],
        'date_created': Date()
    }

    // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newUser,
        url: '/users/adduser',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {

        if (response.msg === '') {
            console.log('user added');
        } else {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
};
```

And here's the route which handles it:

```
/*
 * POST to adduser.
 */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('testcol'); //'testcol' is the name of my collection
    collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

I kind of thought that updating a doc would be just as easy. I'm grabbing the doc by the ident field, which will be unique to each user. However, I can't seem to make the client-side stuff pass to the server. Here's my client-side update:

```
function addError(event) {
event.preventDefault();

    // If it is, compile all user info into one object
    var errorUpdate = {
        '$push': {'error_button': Date()}
    }

    // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        data: errorUpdate,
        url: '/users/errorUpdate',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {

        if (response.msg === '') {
            console.log("update sent, didn't receive an error");
        }
        else {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
};
```

This code executes, but the server-side just throws 500s. Here's that function:

```
 /* 
 * update mongo doc
 */

router.put('/errorUpdate', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('testcol');
    collection.update({'ident': ident},req.body, function(err, result){             
if (err) {
            console.log('Error updating menu: ' + err);
            res.send({'users.js: error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            console.log('doc has been updated');
            res.send(item);
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the node.js console?

Comment: Yeah, a 500: "PUT /users/errorUpdate 500"

Comment: res.send(item);  - where is the item variable declaration?

Comment: That's a good question. Should it be res.send(result)? I'm not sure what I'm doing with res.send().

Comment: Also req.db is the database path (I'm using monk).

Comment: You should send whatever you want to send, but what you want to send should exists :) 
In your example, your javascript callback is expecting to receive an object with a msg property so you should res.send({msg:''});

Comment: Good point. :) Changed it to your suggestion but still getting 500 errors though.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Outside of console logging everything? I know the req is being properly made by the client but the server side stuff isn't executing. That's why I'm posting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and it was a really really stupid mistake.

You might notice in my server-side code I use a variable called `ident`:

```
router.put('/errorUpdate', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('testcol');
collection.update({'ident': ident},req.body, function(err, result)...
```

`ident` is a global variable from my client-side stuff (global.js, which makes the ajax call), and it never made it to the server.

Further, I tried to send the Mongo update statement with the `ident` variable, which is totally unnecessary and just caused headaches.

Here's how I fixed it. This is client-side (where I only send the `ident` variable):

```
function addError(event) {
event.preventDefault();

    // If it is, compile all user info into one object
    var identifyMe = {
        'ident': ident
    }

    // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/users/errors',
        data: identifyMe,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {
        // Check for successful (blank) response
        if (response.msg === '') {
            console.log('update sent, no errors received');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error detected. Response was: ' + response);

        }
    });
};
```

... and this is server-side, where I take that identifier and do the update (this works because all I'm doing is inserting a time stamp):

```
router.post('/errors', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
var identifier = req.body.ident;
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('testcol');
collection.update({'ident': identifier}, {$push: {'error_button': Date()}}, function(err, result){
    res.send(
        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
    );
});
});
```

You might notice that I'm pulling out that `ident` variable from the JSON that's being passed, with `req.body.ident`.

Hope this helps someone else struggling with updating a Mongo doc by posting to Express routes via Ajax with Node! :)